# Classifying spatial metrics value

Tags: landscape, fragstats

I am currently working on my task of analyzing spatial metrics (landscape metrics). I used Fragstats for the analysis. I use class-level analysis for several indexes and need to classify the values into low, medium, and high and visualize them on a map. I try to divide the raster into a 1x1 km grid, but I have no idea on how to classify it.